# IndexOutOfRange Exception in sqldatareader using c#

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I create an application using c# , In my authentification interface , i have a test control , i want to know profile user .

My database contains  table named `user` which contains 4 columns

```
(id_user,name ,mail, profile)
```

Here is my code

```
public string profil_user(string login)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new database().connect_user();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select profile from user where name = '" + login + "';";
        SqlDataReader s = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (s.Read())
        {
           return ( s.GetString(3));


        }
        else{return ("false"); }
    }
```

but i have an exception in `s.GetString(3)`

> system.IndexOutOfRange :  index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: Little Bobby Tables calling

Comment: `s.GetString(0)` because you've just one column returned.

Comment: LBT: [Citation](https://xkcd.com/327/) needed

Comment: Could you clarify whether you actually have four rows (that seems unlikely) or four *columns*?

Answer (score 2):

You're only selecting a single field (`profile`) but then you're trying to select the 4th field (index 3) here:

```
return ( s.GetString(3));
```

In addition to just returning `s.GetString(0)` I would *strongly* advise you to:

- Use parameterized SQL - *always* do this, to prevent [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), make your code more readable, and prevent unexpected text conversion problems
- Either throw an exception or return `null` if the profile isn't found, instead of returning the string "false"
- Use `using` statements for disposable things like `SqlCommand`, `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader` to ensure that you clean up resources appropriately
- Start following [.NET naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) to make your code more idiomatic

So something like:

```
public string GetUserProfile(string login)
{
    string sql = select profile from user where name = @login";
    // I assume Connect() returns an *open* connection?
    using (var conn = new Database().Connect())
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = login;
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // If it's an error (code failure) for there to be no matching profile,
                // you may want to throw an exception instead.
                return s.Read() ? s.GetString(0) : null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want the fourth row, not the fourth column which you try to access with `s.GetString(3)`:

```
int rowNum = 0;
while(s.Read())
{
   if(++rowNum == 4)
   {
      return s.GetString(0);
   }
}
return "false";
```

However, it is a bit strange to access the fourth row when you don't use an `Order By`. You should also only return the row that you want with the correct sql query.

You are also open for sql injection if you use string concatenation here:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select profile from user where name = '" + login + "';";
```

Use sql parameters:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select profile from user where name = @login";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = login;
```

---

> have 4 columns not rows

Ok, so you instead want the fourth column. Why don't you use the name instead?

Since you only select the `profile`-column(the fourth), you could simply use `GetString(0)`. But you could also select all columns and then determine the correct index with [`GetOrdinal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int profileColumnIndex = s.GetOrdinal("profile");
return s.GetString(profileColumnIndex);
```

This is useful if you don't control the query or it might be changed in future.

Comment: I doubt that the OP *really* has 4 rows. I strongly suspect they have four columns instead, and they just wrote the wrong thing in the question.

Comment: Can I give 1+ extra for the last sentence?

Comment: @DaisyShipton: now that i've read it again, it seems you're right. He says rows but he shows columns.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not have all the fields in your select list

Change the SQL to:

```
select id_user,name ,mail, profile from user where name = '" + login + "';
```

Comment: The OP only appears to want a single field to be returned - and your suggestion still leaves the code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting only 1 field, thus index 3 is out of bounds. It also very important to  Use parameters. Try:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select profile from user where name = @login;";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@login, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = login;
SqlDataReader s = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (s.Read())
{   
  return  s[0].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for [SqlDataReader.GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) should be the column index. You're only selecting one column so you get an exception.